# ¿Como hacer un matTooltip que muestre una fila entera de una tabla en Angular?

Tags: html, css, angular

Recojo los datos de la tabla, y en esta parte del codigo una linea.
Esta es la parte de mi codigo en HTML:

```
<ng-container matColumn="col1">
  <th class="cabeceraColumna" mat-header-cell *matHeaderCell mat-sort-header>
    {{'tabla1.titulosColumna.columna1' | translate}}
  </th>
  <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row" matTooltip= {{row.col1}}> {{row.col1}} 
  </td>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: No se puede hacer esto al menos con Angular Material. Lo que planeas no conforma los standares de Material Design https://material.io/components/tooltips/#placement y por tanto la librería no lo contempla. Obviamente es tu código y seguramente puedas "hackear" el estilo añadiendo CSS:after o haciendo interpolación de tu columna, pero no te lo recomendaría.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que puedes hacer es que en el matTooltip le metas una función en el que le envies la row y despues desde el controlador le envias el string concatenando las columnas:

Parte Html:

```
matTooltip= {{toolTipRow(row)}}
```

Parte Ts :

```
toolTipRow: string = (row) => {
return `${row.col1} ${row.col2} ${row.col3} ....`
}
```